# Solve linear nonhomogeneous differential equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve the equation similar [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776759/solve-linear-nonhomogeneous-differential-equation). But now I have the right side as \begin{equation}dx \, H_0(ex+f)e^{-(ex+f)/2}\end{equation} and the homogeneous solution as \begin{equation} y_h(x) =  gH_1(ex+f)e^{-(ex+f)/2}. \end{equation} It is more complicated because after substitution I got the following equation:
\begin{equation} \ddot{C}(x) (\alpha x + \beta) + (\gamma x^2 + \delta x + \epsilon) \dot{C}(x) = \zeta x .\end{equation}
I can't solve it analytically. Can someone give me some tips about solving? Thank you.

Comment: Does no one can help? I really need the solution...